# Stanford CoreNLP: Enhanced++ Dependencies recognition in Java

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

Can I directly looking for **nmod:from** and **nmod:of** Enhanced++ Dependencies  in **Java** code?

```
semanticGraph.getChildrenWithReln(rootToken, UniversalEnglishGrammaticalRelations.NOMINAL_MODIFIER);
```

The second parameter of `getChildrenWithReln` method requires `GrammaticalRelation`. Unfortunatelly, I find only `UniversalEnglishGrammaticalRelations.NOMINAL_MODIFIER` and not something like `UniversalEnglishGrammaticalRelations.NOMINAL_MODIFIER_FROM`.

---

*My temporary solution:*

```
public List<IndexedWord> getChildrenByRelation(IndexedWord root, String shortName, String specific) {
        final List<SemanticGraphEdge> outputEdges = semanticGraphWrapper.get().getOutEdgesSorted(root);
        final List<IndexedWord> tokens = new ArrayList<>();

        GrammaticalRelation relation;
        for (SemanticGraphEdge edge : outputEdges) {
                relation = edge.getRelation();
                if (relation.getShortName().equals(shortName) && relation.getSpecific().equals(specific))
                    tokens.add(edge.getTarget());
        }

        return tokens;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use this method in `edu.stanford.nlp.trees.UniversalEnglishGrammaticalRelations:`

```
public static GrammaticalRelation getNmod(String prepositionString)
```

And supply the preposition you want.